# perl while loop

Tags: linux, perl

In this code I parse a file (containing the output from `ls -lrt`) for a log file's modification date. Then I move all log files into a new folder with their modification dates added to the filenames, and than making a tar of all those files.

The problem I am getting is in the `while` loop. Because it's reading the data for all the files the while loop keeps on running 15 times. I understand that there is some issue in the code but I can't figure it out.

Inside the while loop I am splitting the `ls -lrt` records to find the log file modified date. `$file` is the output of the `ls` command that I am storing in the text file `/scripts/yagya.txt` in order to get the modification date. But the `while` loop is executing 15 times since there are 15 log files in the folder which match the pattern.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use File::Find;
use strict;

my @field;
my $filenew;
my $date;
my $file = `ls -lrt /scripts/*log*`;
my $directory="/scripts/*.log";
my $current = localtime;
my $current_time = $current;
$current_time = s/\s+//g;
my $freetime = $current_time;
my $daytime = substr($current_time,0,8);
my $seconddir = "/$freetime/";

system ("mkdir $seconddir");

open (MYFILE,">/scripts/yagya.txt");
print MYFILE "$file";
close (MYFILE);

my $data = "/scripts/yagya.txt";
my $datas = "/scripts/";
my %options = (
    wanted => \&wanted,
    untaint => 1
);

find (\%options, $datas);
sub wanted {
    if (/[._]log\d*$/){
        my $files;
        my @fields;
        my $fields;
        chomp;
        $files=$_;

        open (MYFILE,$data);
        while(<MYFILE>){
            chop;
            s/#.*//;
            next unless /\S/;
            @fields = (split)[5,6,7];
            $fields = join('',@fields), "\n";
        }
        close (MYFILE);

        system ("mv  $files $seconddir$fields$files");
    }
}

system ("tar cvf /$daytime/$daytime.tar.gz /$daytime/*log*");
system ("rm $seconddir*log*");

system ("rm $data");
```

Comment: please learn how to indent your code.

Comment: Please re-state your problem in a way which someone could understand.

Comment: Try reformulate the question with: 1.) I have this 2.) I want get this 3.) I tried this (already here). Seems, you're trying rewrite a shell script into perl, 6 times calling system(...), like system("rm $data") instead of `unlink $data or warn "Could not unlink $data: $!";`. Can you post the shell script if you have one?

Answer (score 3):

Your code is very difficult to read. It looks like you have written the program as a single big chunk before you started to test it. That way of working is common but very wrong. You should start by implementing a small part of the program and testing that before you add a little more functionality, test again, and so on. That way you won't be overwhelmed with fixing many problems at once in a large untested program.

It would also help you a lot if you added `use warnings` to your `use strict` at the top of the program. It helps to catch simple errors that you may overlook.

Also, are you aware that `File::Find` will call your `wanted` callback subroutine every time it encounters a file? It doesn't pass all the files at once.

The problem seems to be that you are reading all the way through the `yagya.txt` file when you should be stopping when you find the record that matches the current file that `File::Find` has found. What you need to do is to check whether the current record in the `ls` output ends with the name of the current file. If you write the loop like this

```
while (<MYFILE>) {
  if (/\Q$files\E$/) {
    my @fields = (split)[5,6,7];
    $fields = join('',@fields);
    last;
  }
}
```

then `$fields` will end up with the modification date of the current file, which is what you want.

**But** this would be a thousand times easier if you used Perl to read the file modification date for you.

Instead of writing an `ls` listing to a file and reading it back, you should do something like this

```
use File::stat;

my $mtime = localtime(stat($files)->mtime);
```

which will give you a string like `Wed Jun 13 11:25:23 2012`. The date from my `ls` output includes only the month name, day of month, and time of day, like `Jun  8 12:37`. That isn't very specific and you perhaps should at least include a year, but to generate the same string from this `$mtime` you can write

```
my $fields = join '', (split ' ', $mtime)[1,2,3];
```

There is a lot more I could say about your program, but I hope this gets it going for you for now.

---

Another couple of things I have noticed:

- The line `$current_time = s/\s+//g` should be `$current_time =~ s/\s+//g` to remove all spaces from the current time string
- A value like `Sun Jun  3 11:50:54 2012` will be reduced to `SunJun311:53:552012`, and `$daytime` will then take the value `SunJun31` which is incorrect

Comment: and `ls -ltr` for the old files will show year instead the time, like "5 aug 2001" and not "5 aug 11:34"...

Answer (score 1):

I'm usually not recommending using bash instead of perl, but sometimes it is much shorter

this problem has 2 parts:

1. rename files into another directory and adding timestamp into the filenames
2. archive them by every minutes or hours, days ... etc..

for 1.)

```
 find ./scripts -name \*[_.]log\* -type f  -printf "%p\0./logs/%TY%Tm%Td-%TH%Tk%TM-%f\0" | xargs -0 -L 2 mv
```

The above will find all plain files with [_.]log in their names and rename them into the `./logs` directory with timestamp prefix. e.g.

```
./scripts/aaa.log12 get renamed into ./logs/20120403-102233-aaa.log12
```

2.) archiving

```
ls logs | sed 's/\(........-....\).*/\1/' | sort -u | while read groupby
do
    ( cd logs && echo tar cvzf ../$groupby.tgz $groupby* )
done
```

this will create tar archives by timestamp-prefix. (Assumed than the `./logs` contain only files with valid (timestamped) filenames)

Of course, the above sed pattern is not nice, but clearly shows deleting `seconds` from the timestamp - so it is creating archives by minutes. If want another grouping, you can use:

```
sed 's/\(........-..\).*/\1/'  - by hours
sed 's/\(........\).*/\1/' - by days
```

Other:

- the `-printf` for find is supported only in gnu version of find - common in Linux
- usually not a good practice working directly in '/', like `/scripts`, therefore my example uses `./`
- if in your ./scrips subtree exists the same filename with the same timestamp, the mv will overwrite the first, e.g. both of ./scripts/a/a.log and ./scripts/x/a.log with the same timestamp will be renamed into ./logs/TIMESTAMP-a.log